# Safe close all connection from server in IdTCPServer

Tags: delphi-10.2-tokyo

I am trying to deactivate TIdTCPServer while a client is connected. My program stops responding. Can anybody help?
This is my sample code. On the server-side, I open a port and wait for a client to send a text line within 5 seconds.  After receiving it, I send it back to the client and wait for another line.

```
unit port_test;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent,
  IdCustomTCPServer, IdTCPServer, Vcl.StdCtrls, IdContext;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    IdTCPServer1: TIdTCPServer;
    IdTCPServer2: TIdTCPServer;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
    procedure IdTCPServer2Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
    procedure IdTCPServer2Disconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
    procedure IdTCPServer1Disconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
    procedure IdTCPServer2Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);//active or deactive socket1
  var
    i: integer;
begin
    if IdTCPServer1.Active then
      begin
        IdTCPServer1.StopListening;
        if IdTCPServer1.Contexts <>nil then
          begin
            with IdTCPServer1.Contexts.LockList do
              try
                i := 0;
                while i < Count do
                  begin
                    TIdContext(Items[i]).Connection.Disconnect;
                    inc(i);
                  end;
              finally
                IdTCPServer1.Contexts.UnlockList;
              end;
          end;
        IdTCPServer1.Active:= false;
        Button1.Caption:= 'Listening';
      end
    else
      begin
        IdTCPServer1.DefaultPort:= strtoint(edit1.Text);
        IdTCPServer1.Active:= true;
        Button1.Caption:= 'Release';
      end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);////active or deactive socket1
begin
    if IdTCPServer2.Active then
      begin
        IdTCPServer2.Active:= false;
        Button2.Caption:= 'Listening';
      end
    else
      begin
        IdTCPServer2.DefaultPort:= strtoint(edit2.Text);
        IdTCPServer2.Active:= true;
        Button2.Caption:= 'Release';
      end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    memo1.Clear;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
    memo1.Lines.Add(AContext.Binding.IP + ' On Port: '+ inttostr(AContext.Binding.port)+ ' Connected');
    memo1.Lines.Add('Peer Ip: '+ AContext.Binding.PeerIP +' On Peer Port: '+ inttostr(AContext.Binding.PeerPort)
        +' Port: ' + inttostr(AContext.Binding.Port));
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Disconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
    memo1.Lines.Add(AContext.Binding.IP + ' On Port: '+ inttostr(AContext.Binding.port)+ ' DisConnected');
    memo1.Lines.Add('Peer Ip: '+ AContext.Binding.PeerIP +' On Peer Port: '+ inttostr(AContext.Binding.PeerPort)
        +' Port: ' + inttostr(AContext.Binding.Port));
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
  var
    str_tmp: string;
begin
    memo1.Lines.Add('Socket1 Listening___ for 5s');
    try
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadTimeout:= 5000;
    str_tmp:= AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn();
    if AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLnTimedout then
        memo1.Lines.Add('Socket1 Timeout.')
    else
      begin
        memo1.Lines.Add('S1<<'+ str_tmp);
        AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(str_tmp + '!Send Back!');
        memo1.Lines.Add('S1>>'+ str_tmp + '!Send Back!' );
      end;
    Except
      memo1.Lines.Add('Socket1 Err');
    end;

end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer2Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
    memo1.Lines.Add(AContext.Binding.IP + ' On Port: '+ inttostr(AContext.Binding.port)+ ' Connected');
    memo1.Lines.Add('Peer Ip: '+ AContext.Binding.PeerIP +' On Peer Port: '+ inttostr(AContext.Binding.PeerPort)
        +' Port: ' + inttostr(AContext.Binding.Port));
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer2Disconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
    memo1.Lines.Add(AContext.Binding.IP + ' On Port: '+ inttostr(AContext.Binding.port)+ ' DisConnected');
    memo1.Lines.Add('Peer Ip: '+ AContext.Binding.PeerIP +' On Peer Port: '+ inttostr(AContext.Binding.PeerPort)
        +' Port: ' + inttostr(AContext.Binding.Port));
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer2Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
  var
    str_tmp: string;
begin
    memo1.Lines.Add('Socket2 Listening___ for 5s');
    try
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadTimeout:= 5000;
    str_tmp:= AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn();
    if AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLnTimedout then
        memo1.Lines.Add('Socket2 Timeout.')
    else
      begin
        memo1.Lines.Add('S2<<'+ str_tmp);
        AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(str_tmp + '!Send Back!');
        memo1.Lines.Add('S2>>'+ str_tmp + '!Send Back!' );
      end;
    Except
      memo1.Lines.Add('Socket2 Err');
    end;

end;

end.
```

Answer (score 1):

The `TIdTCPServer.Active` property setter deactivates listening and disconnects all active clients.  You don't need to do any of that manually. Just set `Active=False` and let `TIdTCPServer` handle the rest for you.

As for your app not responding, that is likely due to two reasons:

- you are accessing your `TMemo` control in `TIdTCPServer` event handlers without synchronizing with the main UI thread. `TIdTCPServer` events are triggered in the context of worker threads, so you MUST sync access to UI controls when accessing them from outside of the main UI thread.
- your `OnExecute` event handlers are swallowing all Indy exceptions, so the servers do not know when connections are being closed so they can terminate their threads.  That in turn blocks the `Active` property setters, which wait for all active client threads to terminate.  If you do not manually `Disconnect()` a connection when you catch an Indy exception, then you need to re-raise the exception and let the server handle it.

Try something more like this instead:

```pascal
unit port_test;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent,
  IdCustomTCPServer, IdTCPServer, Vcl.StdCtrls, IdContext;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    IdTCPServer1: TIdTCPServer;
    IdTCPServer2: TIdTCPServer;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
    procedure IdTCPServer2Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
    procedure IdTCPServer2Disconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
    procedure IdTCPServer1Disconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
    procedure IdTCPServer2Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure AddToMemo(const S: string);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.AddToMemo(const S: string);
begin
  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(S);
    end
  );
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);//active or deactive socket1
var
  i: integer;
begin
  if IdTCPServer1.Active then
  begin
    IdTCPServer1.Active := False;
    Button1.Caption := 'Listening';
  end
  else
  begin
    IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Clear;
    IdTCPServer1.DefaultPort := StrToInt(Edit1.Text);
    IdTCPServer1.Active := True;
    Button1.Caption := 'Release';
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);////active or deactive socket1
begin
  if IdTCPServer2.Active then
  begin
    IdTCPServer2.Active := False;
    Button2.Caption := 'Listening';
  end
  else
  begin
    IdTCPServer2.Bindings.Clear;
    IdTCPServer2.DefaultPort := StrToInt(Edit2.Text);
    IdTCPServer2.Active := True;
    Button2.Caption := 'Release';
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Clear;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  AddToMemo(AContext.Binding.IP + ' On Port: ' + IntToStr(AContext.Binding.Port) + ' Connected');
  AddToMemo('Peer Ip: ' + AContext.Binding.PeerIP + ' On Peer Port: ' + IntToStr(AContext.Binding.PeerPort) + ' Port: ' + IntToStr(AContext.Binding.Port));

  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadTimeout := 5000;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Disconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  AddToMemo(AContext.Binding.IP + ' On Port: ' + IntToStr(AContext.Binding.Port) + ' DisConnected');
  AddToMemo('Peer Ip: '+ AContext.Binding.PeerIP +' On Peer Port: '+ IntToStr(AContext.Binding.PeerPort) + ' Port: ' + IntToStr(AContext.Binding.Port));
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  str_tmp: string;
begin
  AddToMemo('Socket1 Listening___ for 5s');
  try
    str_tmp := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn();
    if AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLnTimedout then
      AddToMemo('Socket1 Timeout.')
    else
    begin
      AddToMemo('S1<<' + str_tmp);
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(str_tmp + '!Send Back!');
      AddToMemo('S1>>' + str_tmp + '!Send Back!');
    end;
  except
    AddToMemo('Socket1 Err');
    raise;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer2Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  AddToMemo(AContext.Binding.IP + ' On Port: ' + IntToStr(AContext.Binding.Port) + ' Connected');
  AddToMemo('Peer Ip: '+ AContext.Binding.PeerIP + ' On Peer Port: ' + IntToStr(AContext.Binding.PeerPort) + ' Port: ' + IntToStr(AContext.Binding.Port));

  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadTimeout := 5000;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer2Disconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  AddToMemo(AContext.Binding.IP + ' On Port: '+ IntToStr(AContext.Binding.Port) + ' DisConnected');
  AddToMemo('Peer Ip: ' + AContext.Binding.PeerIP + ' On Peer Port: ' + IntToStr(AContext.Binding.PeerPort) + ' Port: ' + IntToStr(AContext.Binding.Port));
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer2Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  str_tmp: string;
begin
  AddToMemo('Socket2 Listening___ for 5s');
  try
    str_tmp := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn();
    if AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLnTimedout then
      AddToMemo('Socket2 Timeout.')
    else
    begin
      AddToMemo('S2<<' + str_tmp);
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(str_tmp + '!Send Back!');
      AddToMemo('S2>>' + str_tmp + '!Send Back!' );
    end;
  except
    AddToMemo('Socket2 Err');
    raise;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thanks to Remy Lebeau. change my code according to your code and all work fine.